# how to add a new row to my grid using ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am having grid with multiple column ,I want to add new random row to it on button click without taking any input externally (from user) in ng-grid using angular Js. please provide me solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: that row should take data to be displayed from the existing JSON data of the grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add rows to your grid. Just add more data to your data-source.

Angular and ng-grid will find out by them self if the data has changed and redraw the grid.

```
  $scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.myData.push($scope.myData[Math.floor((Math.random() * $scope.myData.length) + 1)])
  }
```

This function will add (duplicate) some random entry from myData to the end of the grid.

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ffv3XJB6QODKOurtLgvA?p=preview)

**Update:**

This is of course a very rough randomizer and may sometimes add empty entries.
To add exact rows from an existing array you should write the function like this:

```
  $scope.addRow = function(index) {
    $scope.myData.push($scope.myData[index])
  }
```

Where index is the index of you json array. (obviously)

Btw. Next time give us more Information what you have tried and how your code is written.

Comment: Thanks....it helped. and yea will give related details regarding my tried code from onwards

Comment: hey...its just taking some random row from my provided JSON and contineously adding same on button click...whereas i want everytime it should choose a different data from my JSON to add it to grid..pls suggest the possible alterations. Thanks

Comment: But this function is adding few rows with some null column entries which should not happen..what changes i need to do pls suggest